# Load local html file to Google Glass

Tags: android, android-webview, google-glass, google-gdk

I developed an app for displaying my HTML pages in android. I used webview to display my local html pages. It working fine.I need to use this same local html file to Google Glass. Is it possible? I used below code for android.

```
 File f = copyFile(R.raw.index, "index.html");
        File file = new File(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
        String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
        String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setClassName("com.google.glass.browser", "com.google.glass.browser.WebBrowserActivity");
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimetype);
        mContext.startActivity(i);

private File copyFile(int resourceId, String filename) {
        InputStream in = null; 
        OutputStream out = null;
        File outFile = null;
        try {
            in = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
            outFile = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
            Log.d("TestHTML", "output file" +  outFile.getAbsolutePath());
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("TestHTML", "Failed to copy file", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                in = null;
                out = null;
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }
        return outFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webview in glass, but I found it didn't work well with scrolling etc, and then it was better to just open it up in a browser activity.  I had an HTML file as a resource so before opening it up in the browser I had to copy it to shared memory first, something like this ...

```
File f = copyFile(R.raw.my_html_file, "file.html");
File file = new File(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setClassName("com.google.glass.browser", "com.google.glass.browser.WebBrowserActivity");
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimetype);
mContext.startActivity(i);
```

And then the copyFile method looks like ...

```
private File copyFile(int resourceId, String filename) {
    InputStream in = null; 
    OutputStream out = null;
    File outFile = null;
    try {
        in = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        outFile = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
        Log.d(TAG, "output file" +  outFile.getAbsolutePath());
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to copy file", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in = null;
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
    return outFile;
}
```

This probably isn't a perfect solution, but it works for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: my_html_file is an your folder name inside Raw folder?

Comment: It's the file name, so res/raw/my_html_file.html is referenced by R.raw.my_html_file

Comment: for the android app I'd continue using the web view as you can then put all your branding etc round it, but as there isn't really the space to do that on glass, it's easier to open up the proper glass browser activity.

Comment: Can you please help this...this is my first project

Comment: `file.html` is just the output name of the file, not that important, but can be the same as the original.  Your code looks ok, does it work?

Comment: I don't have google glass...Waiting for someone help.....Does my code is correct?

Comment: You can test it on any android device if you swap out the intent for `i.setClassName("com.google.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");` to use the stock android browser rather than the glass browser.

Comment: So many issue while keep the HTML files inside raw folder...The index.html file is not loading images from other folder and it won't displays the images in html pages.

Comment: StackOverflow is for helping with programming issues that others may also have, not for one-to-one code reviews, if you have another specific issue you can ask another question but I'm afraid I don't have the time to fix all your issues, and this isn't the site for that. Sorry.